# Как передать в функцию переменную по ссылке? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, ссылки, передача-параметров

Хочу сделать что-то вроде этого только для переменной, не списка:

```
def fn(a: list):
    a[0] += 1


b = [2]
fn(b)

print(b) # будет выведенно 3, как я и хочу.
```

Я хочу код на python похожий на этот, написанный на C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fn(int &a) {
    ++a;

}


int main()
{

    int a = 2;
    fn(a);
    cout << a;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def user_sum(a: int, b: int):
    result = a + b
    return result

a = 2

result = user_sum(a, 2)

print(result)
```

Comment: Вам стоит почитать про типы данных list и int и что с ними можно делать

Comment: посмотрите на код, написанный на C++, который я добавил.

Comment: @llollcat в Python нет ссылок на переменные. Так как даже целочисленные переменные там неизменны. При изменении переменной - она не меняется, а создаётся новая в памяти. По этой причине указатели бессмысленны.